# How to identify an unknown entry in `lshw`?

Tags: drivers, unknown-device

I have an unknown entry in my laptop hardware list. I was searching for my bluetooth adapter name and driver when I saw it.

How do I identify what device is that? Also where do I find information on my bluetooth driver?

Snapshot :

[image: Complete snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

The details on that device entry, and for its parent, will give you hints as to what it is. Given the information in the screenshot, it seems to be some PCI-express VGA capabilities/palette related chip.

You'll need to have some understanding of the data you're looking at, and how various pieces of hardware fit together, to be able to make reasonable guesses as to what the Unknown devices are, though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a VGA card (chip), perhaps your 1st Intel Graphics controller (based on the PCI place).